# Does for/list do an unnecessary reverse?

Tags: racket, list-comprehension, reverse, for-comprehension, cons

I was poking around in the Macro Stepper for the first time and noticed that a `for/list` expanded into code involving something called `alt-reverse`. Does `for/list` cons each item onto the front of an empty list and then reverse it? That seems very inefficient.

I wrote a little test:

```
(define (test n)
  (time
    (for/list ([x (in-range n)])
      (list x x)))
  (time
    (for/fold ([result '()])
              ([x (in-range n)])
      (cons (list x x) result)))
  (void))
```

Indeed the `for/list` version runs in about 150% of the time of `for/fold` without `reverse`, the difference apparently due entirely to additional garbage collection:

```
> (test 500000)
cpu time: 1059 real time: 2079 gc time: 940
cpu time: 614 real time: 1231 gc time: 550
> (test 500000)
cpu time: 1060 real time: 3889 gc time: 907
cpu time: 770 real time: 1363 gc time: 699
> (test 500000)
cpu time: 1035 real time: 2479 gc time: 917
cpu time: 736 real time: 2535 gc time: 651
```

It sounds like I shouldn't get in the habit of calling `for/list`. Is there a more efficient way to make a list in "forward" order (i.e. where the last item evaluated is the last item in the list)?

Comment: Your version using `for/fold` doesn’t do the same thing the `for/list` version does, since it never uses `result` at all.

Comment: @AlexisKing Oops! Thanks. I just fixed it. Now updating the question with new results…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the Git history, I see that a change to make `for/list` avoid `reverse` was [committed](https://github.com/racket/racket/commit/5e94a906cd5935735283df93dd263db051cda3e4), but [it didn't work](https://github.com/racket/racket/commit/51bf69e3562bdbc45184eabe1722da135431ea43) because of a subtle interaction with continuations that could tigger quadtradic-time behavior. (I do wonder if the upcoming move to a Chez Scheme backend might mean that "when Racket one day gets a better implementation of continuations" could actually be coming soon.)

You can build a list in "forward" order by, as the first commit message put it, "`cons`ing onto a recursive call." The Racket Guide sections on [Tail Recursion](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Lists__Iteration__and_Recursion.html#%28part._tail-recursion%29) and [Recursion versus Iteration](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Lists__Iteration__and_Recursion.html#%28part._.Recursion_versus_.Iteration%29) actually discuss the trade-offs between the `map`-style and `for/fold`-style approaches in some detail.

Also, for future reference, the Racket community tends to live more on the very active and friendly [racket-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users) and to some extent the Slack channel than here on Stack Overflow.